# gen_server:reply/2: format of message sent to client

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, gen-server

When I call `gen_server:reply/2`:

```
gen_server:reply(From, Msg),
```

the client, `From`, receives a message with the format:

```
{Ref, Msg)
```

I can't find any documentation for the message format sent by `gen_server:reply/2`, and I'm wondering how I can pattern match the `Ref` in the message.  Currently, I use a don't care variable for the `Ref`:

```
receive
    {_Ref, Msg} -> Msg;
    Other -> Other
end
```

which means that a process other than the `gen_server` could potentially send my client a message that would match the `{_Ref, Msg}` clause.

Comment: If you use your own `receive` why do you use `gen_server` at all? I am pretty sure that the format of messages used by `gen_server` is an undocumented implementation detail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the call `gen_server:reply(From, Msg)`, `From` is not simply the client: it is in fact a tuple containing two values, the process id of the caller and a unique reference.  We can see this in [the implementation of `gen_server:reply/2`](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/09abac433a59f0644316a54f61ade7132db673d1/lib/stdlib/src/gen_server.erl#L248-L252):

```
%% -----------------------------------------------------------------
%% Send a reply to the client.
%% -----------------------------------------------------------------
reply({To, Tag}, Reply) ->
    catch To ! {Tag, Reply}.
```

The idea is that `Tag` is a unique value provided by the caller, so that the caller can distinguish the result from this call from any other incoming message:

```
Ref = make_ref(),
MyServer ! {'$gen_call', {self(), Ref}, foo},
receive
    {Ref, Reply} -> io:format("Result of foo call: ~p~n", [Reply])
end
```

In the code above, the `receive` will block until it gets a response to this very call.

(`gen_server:call/2` does something like the above, and additionally monitors the server in case it crashes, and checks for timeouts.)

The reason this is undocumented is that it is considered an internal implementation detail subject to change, and users are advised to rely on `gen_server:call` and `gen_server:reply` instead of generating and matching the messages themselves.

---

Most of the time you wouldn't need to use `gen_server:reply/2` at all: the server process receives a call and handles it synchronously, returning a `reply` tuple:

```
handle_call(foo, _From, State) ->
    %% ignoring 'From' here, because we're replying immediately
    {reply, foo_result, State}.
```

But sometimes you'd want the server process to delay replying to the call, for example waiting for network input:

```
handle_call(foo, From, State) ->
    send_request(foo),
    NewState = State#state{pending_request = From},
    {noreply, NewState}.

handle_info({received_response, Response}, State = #state{pending_request = From}) ->
    gen_server:reply(From, Response),
    NewState = State#state{pending_request = undefined},
    {noreply, NewState}.
```

In the example above, we save the `From` value in the server state, and when the response comes in as an Erlang message, we forward it to the caller, which will block until it gets the response.  (A more realistic example would handle  multiple requests concurrently and match incoming responses to outstanding requests somehow.)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195725/discussion-on-answer-by-legoscia-gen-serverreply-2-format-of-message-sent-to-c).

Answer (score 1):

It is a [gen.erl](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/lib/stdlib/src/gen.erl) feature used by gen_* behaviors. You can see [gen_event's call](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/lib/stdlib/src/gen_event.erl#L244), [gen_server's call](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/lib/stdlib/src/gen_server.erl#L211) and [gen_statem's call](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/lib/stdlib/src/gen_statem.erl#L611).
So how does it work?
The Idea is simple, when you call [gen:call/4](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/lib/stdlib/src/gen.erl#L152) or `gen:call(Process, Label, Request, Timeout)`, It monitors `Process`. So `erlang:monitor/2` yields a reference.  It uses this reference and sends message to `Process` in form of `{Label, {self(), Ref}, Request}`. After that it waits for `{Ref, Reply}` for specified `Timeout` and after receiving reply it demonitors `Process`. Also if `Process` crashes during sending `Reply` or even if `Process` was a dead pid before call, it receives `{'DOWN', Ref, _, _, Reason}`.

For example `gen_server:call/2-3` call `gen:call(Prpcess, '$gen_call', Req, Timeout)`. When server `Process` (which is a gen_server) receives it, It assumes that it's a call request, so calls your handle_call function, etc.

Comment: I think that the answer - which is very good - should explicitly say that gen.erl is an internal helper module, and not part of "official" OTP published interface. As such it can be modified without warning.

Comment: @WojtekSurowka of course. But I'm sure there are some libs out there using this module because it's stable enough.